# Por que o acordo ortográfico foi feito?

Tags: acordo-ortográfico

Mesmo após o acordo ortográfico ainda estão mantidas diversas diferenças entre o português europeu e o brasileiro. Porém no Brasil foi feita uma grande propaganda em cima desse acordo e por diversas vezes falava-se que ele serviria para unificar os dois dialetos o que não aconteceu de fato. Então se não era esse objetivo, por que o acordo ortográfico foi feito?

Comment: A ideia era tentar unificar ao máximo os dois dialetos, mas há coisas que não se podem passar por cima, como por exemplo **fato** que em Portugal é um terno. Então haveria confusão com fato (terno) e fato (de facto).

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho realmente complicado por esse ponto, outro exemplo é com "Bichas" que em portugal é o mesmo que "Filas" para nós, mas se falar essa palavra aqui é um chingamento. O que não entendo é por que tentar unificar os dialetos, não seria mais interessante manter eles separados para evitar esse tipo de confusão?

Comment: E esses termos continuam separados. A ideia é tentar que haja mais facilidade de comunicação entre povos que falam português. Já há muita coisa unificada. Se reparares no SOpt quase não se nota diferença de um Português para Brasileiro nas perguntas e respostas.

Comment: A pergunta do título poderá ter uma resposta objetiva e oficial. A pergunta efetiva (Então se não era esse objetivo, de que esse acordo serviu?) é primarily opinion based.

Comment: @GitGud revisei e mudei a pergunta efetiva, realmente estava baseada em  opinião do modo que estava

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, hoje quase não temos diferença, mesmo sendo possivel perceber pela forma como o europeu e o brasileiro escrevem. Uma coisa que tenho percebido é que por vezes tenho passado a escrever mais como o europeu. Talvez por sempre ter achado o dialeto europeu mais bonito de pronunciar, mas tenho adquirido esse costume inconsientemente desde a SO-pt e agora nessa nova exchange.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth eu sou suspeito para falar mas concordo inteiramente contigo :)

Comment: Grande pergunta e mais que nada eu acho interessante descobrir os acordos políticos que motivaram a decisão. Não o *press-release* oficial onde tudo são flores e luzes.

Comment: Note que esse não é o primeiro acordo ortográfico feito, meus pais têm livros dos anos 50/60 que são anteriores a outro acordo, no qual também vários acentos foram suprimidos. A real intenção aí é incremental, simplificar a escrita onde fosse possível. E já que isso seria feito, era melhor sincronizar entre os vários países essa simplificação para evitar aumentar as diferenças. Mas quando isso chega à imprensa, uma pitada de sensacionalismo é indispensável.

Answer (score 7):

O texto integral do acordo ortográfico de 1990, ao qual estamos nos referindo aqui, está [disponível](http://www.priberam.pt/docs/AcOrtog90.pdf) na Internet. O anexo II desse documento explica que a razão para introduzi-lo foi justamente reduzir as diferenças ortográficas entre as variantes brasileira e europeia da língua, e explica individualmente os motivos por trás de cada uma das mudanças introduzidas.

Eu pessoalmente não consigo entender os motivos dados para a maior parte das mudanças propostas, visto que as maiores diferenças entre os dialetos, mesmo aquelas que transparecem na escrita, advêm de escolhas de vocabulário e gramaticais, e não de escolhas ortográficas. As reformas de acentuação são particularmente estranhas; não vejo qual o problema em se escrever "gôsto" (substantivo) para diferenciá-lo de "gosto" (verbo).

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade, a intenção do acordo ortográfico não foi unir os dois dialetos, até porque isso seria (é) impossível.
A real intenção do acordo ortográfico foi fazer com os dois dialetos ficassem mais parecidos e sem tanta inconsistência (na ortografia) e, também, aumentar o prestígio social da língua no cenário internacional.

Se pararmos pra analisar, quem escreve ou lê inglês britânico consegue entender muito bem o inglês americano, já que são pouquíssimas as diferenças na ortografia. O nosso português (brasileiro) era tão diferente do europeu que era muito difícil conseguirmos ler algo que fosse escrito por um português e vice-versa.
Não tenho plena certeza de que agora está mais fácil já que eu só comecei a interagir com pessoas de Portugal depois do acordo, mas nós podemos ver no **SOpt** (como disse o *Jorge B.* nos comentários) que é bem tranquilo nós entendermos os portugueses e vice-versa.

Comment: Tem certeza que as ortografias eram tão diferentes assim? Elas me parecem estar no mesmo patamar das diferenças do inglês britânico e americano (ou seja, uma palavra diferente aqui e outra acolá). Alguns acentos em éi, éu, ôo, êe não me parecem ser de tão grande importância para reimprimir livros e dificultar a vida dos estudantes. Poderiam pelo menos ter consertado a berin[jg]ela: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/675/diferen%C3%A7as-de-ortografia-entre-beringela-e-berinjela

Comment: Também não concordo de jeito nenhum que acentos em duplas de letras de palavras que contenham: -éi; -ói; -ôo e  -êe causem tanto alvoroço na reimpressão de livros, jornais ou revistas, quer sejam as pessoas estudantes ou não. A prova disso é que minha prima emprestou-me um livro de versão escolar e eu parei no meio do caminho pois além de ter falta de concentração, encontrei a palavra "paranóia" ou "paranóico" —não me lembro—(mas escrita segundo este Acordo) e nem terminei de lê-lo, de tanta raiva. Quanto à berinjela, não sei o que dizer.

Comment: A sua comparação com a língua inglesa é completamente inválida. O inglês britânico e o americano são inteligíveis justamente porque nunca houve (e tomara que nunca haja) uma reforma ortográfica na língua inglesa, exceto, talvez, a tentativa de Webster nos EUA, que introduziu variantes como "center" para "centre", "color" para "colour" e outras bobagens. A ortografia inglesa congelou no tempo e a evidência está na fonética, que não tem quase relação nenhuma com a escrita desde o período elizabetano. Se os falantes do português parassem de bagunçar na ortografia, seria muito melhor para todos.

Comment: @Apollo Em qual momento eu falei que o motivo da semelhança entre a língua inglesa se deu por uma reforma ortográfica?

Comment: @JéfBueno Eu não disse que você disse que a língua inglesa foi reformada em nenhum momento. Na sua resposta vc faz um paralelo entre o inglês e o português, argumentando que o português criou ramificações ortográficas (e sugerindo indiretamente, suponho, que isso não ocorreu no inglês). Eu estou dizendo que essa comparação não funciona porque o português sofre de repetidas tentativas de reforma, o que não ocorre na língua inglesa. (Provavelmente as ramificações do português se manteriam perfeitamente inteligíveis se ninguém tentasse reformá-las.) Os dois casos são incompatíveis.