# Diferenças de ortografia entre "beringela" e "berinjela"

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico

A palavra "**berinjela**" é escrita com `j` no Brasil e com `g` em Portugal e outros países.

Por que existe esta diferença?

Isso não foi resolvido pelo novo acordo ortográfico?

Comment: O Brasil possui a sua própria Norma Ortográfica que difere da portuguesa. Comentaristas de diários de direita portugueses, vários, aproveitam-se para ironizar o fato de Dilma Rousseff ter adotado a forma 'presidenta'. Esta gente de maneira obtusa se fiou unicamente na Norma Portuguesa e se esqueceu que o Brasil tem sua própria Norma que admite as duas formas, a presidente e a presidenta, apenas a 2ª é menos usada. O Acordo Ortográfico foi feito para dar uma MÍNIMA escrita comum (alteração entre 1,5% a 2% das palavras somente) entre as duas vertentes do português e não para unificar tudo.

Comment: No Brasil normalmente se escreve com j as palavras de origem árabe, africana e tupi (indígena).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As grafias diferentes existem por a palavra original ser árabe e haver diferentes tradições lexicográficas em Portugal e no Brasil.

Segundo [Pedro Mendes, nas dúvidas linguísticas do FLiP](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=506):

> [Beringela](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/dlpo.aspx?pal=beringela) é a forma preferencial e é a única forma atestada em todas as obras de referência consultadas para o português europeu. A forma *berinjela* aparece apenas registada em dicionários ou vocabulários brasileiros. De entre os dicionários brasileiros, o *Dicionário Aurélio* e o *Vocabulário Ortográfico da Academia Brasileira de Letras* registam apenas a forma *berinjela*, enquanto o dicionário *Aulete Digital* e o *Dicionário Houaiss* registam as duas formas (este último regista *berinjela* explicitamente como forma não preferencial, remetendo-a para a forma *beringela*).
>
> Esta diferença de registos deve-se essencialmente à existência, em português, de duas consoantes para representação do mesmo som, o que originou, em muitas palavras de origem árabe (veja-se, por exemplo, casos como *alfange/alfanje*, *alforge/alforje* ou *alquequenge/alquequenje*), duas tradições lexicográficas distintas, no português europeu tendencialmente com *g*, no português brasileiro tendencialmente com *j*.
>
> Deve referir-se ainda, a este respeito, que a aplicação do [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](http://www.priberam.pt/docs/AcOrtog90.pdf) não altera nem resolve estas divergências ortográficas.
>
> Bibliografia: Rebelo GONÇALVES, *Tratado de Ortografia da Língua Portuguesa*, Coimbra: Atlântida, 1947, pp. 26-27.